# Keycloak 1.9.1.Final- failed verification of token: Token is not active

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to connect a Spring App Keycloak, but I get this error:

After I enter to my app, and I was redirected to Keycloak for authentication, I receive an error in my browser:

```
192.168.1.66 redirected you too many times.
```

Full url

```
URL: http://192.168.1.66:9092/keycloak-sp-example/sso/login?state=139%2F1ed115fb-4d4f-468c-9a72-845f9cfa9cdb&code=PVGhg5X28G8fjNt36tMGHTJIP7CQdHOhoK4XhPgUh3E.2d885db5-5c4f-43b1-9095-305494718a97
```

And, in the console, I got:

```
ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator - failed verification of token: Token is not active.
```

It's a bug? Or is anything that I should configure in the console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem, I was testing the product in a virtual machine without the correct time zone configured.

Comment: Thank you  @ignacio Ocamp , it takes me a lot to find what's the cause of issue

Answer (score 2):

Try to sync the server timing of Keycloak and application server or else increase the access token life span which is not recommended.